# QTP using the same Data table for different Tests

Tags: qtp

Using QTP I would like to use a single excel file (DataTable) for different tests.
Is this possible? As I am able to use it for different actions but not for different tests.

Comment: Yes, you can if you intend to use same data

Comment: I agree: Yes it is possible. If you want to know how, look at the ImportSheet function, develop an approach using that function, and come back with your code, edit it into your question and ask a question about that code. Please!

Answer (score 1):

As one comment already mentioned, you can look at the ImportSheet function. But for a more general understanding of how this approach works, search for data-driven frameworks in QTP. [Here](http://www.automationrepository.com/2012/06/qtp-data-driven-framework-architecture-part-2/) is a great article on the topic.

Comment: +1 since you obviously are just hunting for the respect points :-)